# CREATE STORED PROCEDURES IN MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a stored procedure in MySQL5 and got this error ***" as is not valid in this position expecting ';'"***. This error is at the last ***' as' keyword in the query*** and I couldn't figure out what the cause is. Please help me look at it.

```
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS load_content;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE load_content()
BEGIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT
        ca.id AS id, cp.provider_id  AS cpId,
        ca.license_start_date AS startDateTime,
        ca.license_end_date   AS endDateTime,
        ca.content_group_id AS contentGroupId,
        ca.episode AS episode,
        ca.series_id AS seriesId,
        ca.is_episode AS isEpisode,
        aw.stage_code AS stageCode,
        tal.title  AS title,
        tal.synopsis  AS synopsis,
        ta.content_type AS contentType
        FROM (SELECT * FROM content_asset
        WHERE (':startDateTime' is null OR license_start_date<=':startDateTime')
        AND (':endDateTime' is null OR license_end_date >=':endDateTime')
        AND(':id'is null OR id=':id')AND(':isEpisode'is null OR is_episode= ':isEpisode')) as ca 
        INNER JOIN title_asset ta ON ca.title_asset_id = ta.id
        INNER JOIN (select * from title_asset_localized
        WHERE (':title' is null OR title like CONCAT('%', ':title', '%'))
        AND language = ':language') tal ON ta.id = tal.title_asset_id
        INNER JOIN (select * from content_provider
        WHERE (':cpId' is null OR provider_id like CONCAT('%', ':cpId', '%' ) )) cp
        ON cp.idx = ca.provider_id
        INNER JOIN (select * from asset_workflow
        WHERE asset_type = ':contentManagementType'
        AND (coalesce(':stageCode') is null OR stage_code in (':stageCode'))) as aw ON aw.asset_id = ca.id) as ca;
END $$
```

Comment: 1) The error message does not come from mysql. 2) I think your are mixing up mysql stored procedures with parametrised sql statements. I think you need the latter, not a stored proc. If you do need a stored proc, then you need to pass the parameters as parameters to the stored procedure, not directly to the sql statement.

Comment: indenting correctly your sub/nested queries will help debugging

Comment: I think there's a parenthesis error around `tal on ta.id ...`. As written it seems to apply to just the `where` conditions of the preceding `select`.

Comment: @khelwood yes, I have also corrected the  missing parenthesis at `tal` but it's the same error

Comment: MySQL does not allow: 1) incorrect parenthesis (excess and/or unpaired); 2) incorrect quote chars (each type have its own special meaning).

Comment: In your particular case - there are excess parenthesis and excess alias.

Comment: Thank so much @Akina could you please me some direction to follow to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure must look similar to this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE load_content(in_startDateTime DATETIME,
                              in_endDateTime DATETIME,
                              in_id INT,
                              in_isEpisode BOOLEAN,
                              in_title TEXT,
                              in_language CHAR(2),
                              in_cpId TEXT,
                              in_contentManagementType TEXT,
                              in_stageCode INT)
SELECT DISTINCT
       ca.id AS id, 
       cp.provider_id  AS cpId,
       ca.license_start_date AS startDateTime,
       ca.license_end_date   AS endDateTime,
       ca.content_group_id AS contentGroupId,
       ca.episode AS episode,
       ca.series_id AS seriesId,
       ca.is_episode AS isEpisode,
       aw.stage_code AS stageCode,
       tal.title  AS title,
       tal.synopsis  AS synopsis,
       ta.content_type AS contentType
       FROM ( SELECT * 
              FROM content_asset
              WHERE (in_startDateTime is null OR license_start_date<=in_startDateTime)
               AND (in_endDateTime is null OR license_end_date >=in_endDateTime)
               AND(in_id is null OR id=in_id)
               AND(in_isEpisode is null OR is_episode= in_isEpisode)
             ) as ca 
       INNER JOIN title_asset ta ON ca.title_asset_id = ta.id
       INNER JOIN ( select * 
                    from title_asset_localized
                    WHERE (in_title is null OR title like CONCAT('%', in_title, '%'))
                      AND language = in_language
                   ) tal ON ta.id = tal.title_asset_id
       INNER JOIN ( select * 
                    from content_provider
                    WHERE (in_cpId is null OR provider_id like CONCAT('%', in_cpId, '%' ) )
                   ) cp ON cp.idx = ca.provider_id
       INNER JOIN ( select * 
                    from asset_workflow
                    WHERE asset_type = in_contentManagementType
                      AND (in_stageCode is null OR stage_code = in_stageCode)
                  ) as aw ON aw.asset_id = ca.id;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, your solution actually gave me insight into getting it working by adding the required number of columns to the parameters.